# Disable springboot request checking when clicking html link

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using springboot with html pages. When i click a link (which is just a redirect a href) to navigate to next page the springboot shows whitelabel error page. Springboot check for the requestmapping when i clicking a a href. I want to disable this. when i click a link i dont want the springboot to check for the request mapping.

Comment: So if the rerquest mapping doesn't exist what *exactly* is meant to happen???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Path Matching and Content Negotiation**

> Spring MVC can map incoming HTTP requests to handlers by looking at
>   the request path and matching it to the mappings defined in your
>   application (for example, @GetMapping annotations on Controller
>   methods).
>
> By default, Spring Boot serves static content from a directory called
>   /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources) in the
>   classpath or from the root of the ServletContext. It uses the
>   ResourceHttpRequestHandler from Spring MVC so that you can modify that
>   behavior by adding your own WebMvcConfigurer and overriding the
>   addResourceHandlers method.
>
> In a stand-alone web application, the default servlet from the
>   container is also enabled and acts as a fallback, serving content from
>   the root of the ServletContext if Spring decides not to handle it.
>   Most of the time, this does not happen (unless you modify the default
>   MVC configuration), because Spring can always handle requests through
>   the DispatcherServlet.

You have to define the behavior of fallback method.